# Problems with installation PngQuant on Debian 7 x64

Tags: linux, image, debian, png, libpng

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
git clone git://github.com/pornel/pngquant.git
cd pngquant
./configure
make
```

I try to install `pngquant` on Debian 7 x64, but when I executed the command `make` I get some error.

```
gcc -O3 -fno-math-errno -funroll-loops -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -std=c99 -I. -DNDEBUG -DUSE_SSE=1 -msse -mfpmath=sse -Wno-unknown-pragmas -I/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include -I/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include -fexcess-precision=fast   -c -o pngquant.o pngquant.c
In file included from pngquant.c:66:0:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h: In function 'fileno':
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:39:17: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h: In function 'fdopen':
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:56:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h: At top level:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:74:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'fwrite' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:97:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'snprintf' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h:98:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'vsnprintf' [enabled by default]
In file included from pngquant.c:67:0:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h:39:29: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h:41:29: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'calloc' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h:42:29: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'realloc' [enabled by default]
In file included from pngquant.c:68:0:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:12:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memchr' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:13:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memcmp' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:14:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memcpy' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:16:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memmove' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:17:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'memset' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:26:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strcspn' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:30:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:32:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strncat' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:34:14: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strncmp' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:35:16: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strncpy' [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/string.h:42:17: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'strspn' [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdint.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/sys/types.h:10,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from pngquant.c:72:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/bitsize/stdint.h:27:0: warning: "__INT64_C" redefined [enabled by default]
pngquant.c:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdint.h:8:0,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/sys/types.h:10,
                 from /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/unistd.h:11,
                 from pngquant.c:72:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/bitsize/stdint.h:28:0: warning: "__UINT64_C" redefined [enabled by default]
pngquant.c:1:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from rwpng.h:38:0,
                 from pngquant.c:90:
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h:1667:52: warning: 'struct tm' declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h:1667:52: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/png.h:1671:49: error: unknown type name 'time_t'
pngquant.c: In function 'main':
pngquant.c:315:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'atof' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
pngquant.c: In function 'write_image':
pngquant.c:791:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'unlink' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
make: *** [pngquant.o] Error 1
```

What's wrong? I also have have another Debian 7 x64 server, but there no installation error like this.

Comment: Please have a look at the file list for syslinux-common https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/syslinux-common/filelist → → There's  no "/usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/". And : pngquant is not supposed to use those headers. And, and ... the headers origins from a Debian 6 package : https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/syslinux-common/filelist . ? Could the files be some leftover from an update Deb 6 to Deb 7 ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen, I able to install, by deleting folder `/usr/lib/syslinux/`